# Why is passing bytes to class str constructor special?

Tags: python-3.x

Offical Python3 docs say this about passing `bytes` to the single argument constructor for `class str`:

> Passing a bytes object to str() without the encoding or errors
>   arguments falls under the first case of returning the informal string
>   representation (see also the -b command-line option to Python).

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str

*informal string representation* -> Huh?

Using the Python console (REPL), and I see the following weirdness:

```
>>> ''
''
>>> b''
b''
>>> str()
''
>>> str('')
''
>>> str(b'')
"b''"  # What the heck is this?
>>> str(b'abc')
"b'abc'"
>>> "x" + str(b'')
"xb''"  # Woah.
```

(The question title can be improved -- I'm struggling to find a better one.  Please help to clarify.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept behind `str` seems to be that it returns a "nicely printable" string, usually in a *human understandable* form.  The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) actually uses the phrase "nicely printable":

> If neither encoding nor errors is given, str(object) returns
>   object.__str__(), which is the “informal” or nicely printable string
>   representation of object. For string objects, this is the string
>   itself. If object does not have a __str__() method, then str() falls
>   back to returning repr(object).

With that in mind, note that `str` of a tuple or list produces string versions such as:

```
>>> str( (1, 2) )
'(1, 2)'
>>> str( [1, 3, 5] )
'[1, 3, 5]'
```

Python considers the above to be the "nicely printable" form for these objects.  With that as background, the following seems a bit more reasonable:

```
>>> str(b'abc')
"b'abc'"
```

With no encoding provided, the bytes `b'abc'` are just bytes, not characters.  Thus, `str` falls back to the "nicely printable" form and the six character string `b'abc'` is nicely printable.