# Send OpenCV image and decode using base64: why not compatible?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, base64, opencv3.0, opencv, python

I need to encode image into binary, send it to server and decode it back to image again.
The decoding method is:

```
def decode_from_bin(bin_data):
    bin_data = base64.b64decode(bin_data)
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(bin_data), dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    return img
```

We use OpenCV to encode image:

```
def encode_from_cv2(img_name):
    img = cv2.imread(img_name, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)  # adjust with EXIF
    bin = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1]
    return str(base64.b64encode(bin))[2:-1] # Raise error if I remove [2:-1]
```

You can run with:

```
raw_img_name = ${SOME_IMG_NAME}

encode_image = encode_from_cv2(raw_img_name)
decode_image = decode_from_bin(encode_image)

cv2.imshow('Decode', decode_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

My question is: why do we have to strip the first two characters from base64 encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyse what happens inside `encode_from_cv2`.

The output of `base64.b64encode(bin)` is a `bytes` object.
When you pass it to `str` in `str(base64.b64encode(bin))`, the `str` function creates a "nicely printable" version of the `bytes` object, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29726742/16401339).

In practice `str` represents the `bytes` object as you see it when you print it, i.e. with a leading `b'` and a traling `'`.
For example

```
>>> base64.b64encode(bin)
b'/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD'
>>> str(base64.b64encode(bin))
"b'/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD'"
```

That's why you need to remove these characters to obtain the encoded string.

In general, this is not the best way to convert a `bytes` object to string, because an encoding is needed to specify how to interpret `bytes` as characters. Here the `str` function uses the default ASCII encoding.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/606205/16401339), you can replace
`str(base64.b64encode(bin))[2:-1]` with `str(base64.b64encode(bin), "utf-8")` to get rid of the slice.